# not able to install Keras on Windows using Conda

Tags: python, windows, installation, keras, anaconda

I am getting dependency conflicts for `keras` and `keras-gpu` when installing via conda shell on Windows.
Earlier the conflicts were between `nltk` and `keras` and I uninstalled `nltk` package. But even now the following conflict exists:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda install keras
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports.functools_lru_cache
  - keras
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How do I resolve this error and successfully install `keras` and `keras-gpu`?

Comment: https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: @silent_dev may I ask which step you try to fix?

Comment: OK~ I fixed it after 
`conda update conda` and 
`conda update --all` in py3.6